# google map как показать на карте что Крым принадлежит Украине

Tags: google-maps

Вот с такой проблемой столкнулся, что на карте крым отделен границей от Украины, можно както поправить (не в политическом смысле:)) 
js

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC58DWA6zPQKbZC6T7XOleuCs4JS5_2FJM&language=uk&libraries=visualization">
```

Comment: Либо берите другую карту, которая считает что Крым - Украинская территория, либо(если карта должна быть статичной) - просто отфотошопьте всё это дело

Comment: Отображение карты и принадлежность Крыма зависит от страны, из которой заходит пользователь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я нашел решение проблемы - в конце скрипта можно указывать регион `&region=UA` тогда показывает что Крым Украины.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC58DWA6zPQKbZC6T7XOleuCs4JS5_2FJM&language=uk&region=UA"></script>
```